# jQuery catch image load no matter if it fired or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, asynchronous, jquery-callback

I am creating an `Image` javascript object and setting it a `src`.

In a separate place, I want to create a canvas object and draw this image once it has been loaded. The problems are -

1. it could be cached (a known issue);
2. the load event could have fired by the moment I want to attach a callback.

Is there a nice way for the callback to be called **even** if the load event has already fired and if the image is cached as well?

I really don't want to modify URL's by appending hashes and magic. The task is - if the image hasn't been loaded by now, wait for load and call the callback function; if it has been loaded already, just call the callback function.